Steps for Forecasting with known copula's parameters
I want to calculate the Mean absolute percentage error (MAPE) for my copula model. I am stuck at the forecasting step. I am not specifying the copula here for different data pairs.

I have two time series X and Y. I found the best GARCH parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ assuming 0 mean.
The Kendals tau between two variables is $\tau$
Then I found the best copula and had its parameters say $\kappa$ and $\omega$.
Now for forecasting, I need to generate residuals using my copula parameters found in step 3.

How to do this if I want to enter the copula parameters MANUALLY and not use some param=fit type of code in R.
I can work in R as well as Excel. Please if somebody could help me with the exact steps of point 4.
Problem Attachment- 
More details attachment- 
Original paper- Patton (2006)- See page 542

Have a look at this. It may help. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/525759/how-to-forecast-from-garch-copula-model

@ Dr. Statistics- Thank you, I did check the above link, it has a single line "Generate pseudo observations from FITTED COPULA", that's exactly what I want to find out, how to do that?

If you want to simulate from the fitted copula, it is the same way as simulate from any copula. sim_fitted-copula <- rCopula(n=your_sample_size, your_fitted_copula(the estimated parameters of the fitted copula)) for example, if your fitted copula was Clayton with parameters equal 5. Then, Sim <- rCopula(1000, claytonCopula(5,dim=3)) ## 3 is the dimension of your data, and n=the sample size.

@ Dr. Statistics - Thank you so so so much. I have been looking for this information all over , and couldn't find exact simple answer the way you explained. My question is, "Is there no role of the correlation when simulating from fitted copula". Because that is what confused me. I have been using time-varying copulas & thought simulation would need correlation, and got lost. Can you plz plz explain this. I have attached my problem in a nutshell to original question, which I have been struggling with for more than 2 months. I will be truly indebted if you could comment. Thank you once again.

What is Λ? Please provide more details.

@ Dr. Statistics- Apologies for not providing full details earlier. I am using Paton (2006) time-varying (dynamic ) copulas where the correlation $\Omega$ follows an Arma process and is mean reverting. $\Lambda$ is the logistic transformation for keeping the correlation within limits. . I have attached an image of more details as well as link to Patons original Paper.

I am unfamiliar with forecasting too much, but it will help based on the provided screenshot. If you want to transform Patton's codes or model from Matlab to R, then you may look at this package. here
In the following code, I first define the necessary parameters and functions based on the information provided in the image. Then, I generate the u1_t and u2_t functions, which are used to calculate the epsilon1_t and epsilon2_t functions. Finally, I generate the vectors epsilon1_vec and epsilon2_vec containing 100 values each, which can be used for forecasting and comparing models.
library(tidyverse)

# Given parameters
w_0 = 0.0433
beta_n = -0.1718
sigma_n = 0.6016
rho_0 = -0.0699

# Time-varying normal copula equation
C_n <- function(u1, u2, p) {
  int1 <- integrate(function(s) exp(-(s^2 - 2*p*s + 1)/(2*(1 - p^2))), 0, u1)$value
  int2 <- integrate(function(s) exp(-(s^2 - 2*p*s + 1)/(2*(1 - p^2))), 0, u2)$value
  (2 * pi * sqrt(1 - p^2))^-1 * exp(-((int1 + int2)/2))
}

# Dynamic equation for dependence parameter p ## you need to muliply it with Λ
p_t <- function(t) {
  w_0 + beta_n*p_t(t-1) + sigma_n * (1/10) * sum(pnorm(u1_t(t-i), 0, 1) * pnorm(u2_t(t-i), 0, 1))
}

# Generating u1_t and u2_t
u1_t <- function(t) pnorm(rnorm(1, 0, 1))
u2_t <- function(t) pnorm(rnorm(1, 0, 1))

# Generating epsilon1_t and epsilon2_t
epsilon1_t <- function(t) -log(-log(u1_t(t)))
epsilon2_t <- function(t) -log(-log(u2_t(t)))

# Generate the vectors for forecasting and comparing models
epsilon1_vec <- sapply(1:100, epsilon1_t)
epsilon2_vec <- sapply(1:100, epsilon2_t)


Thank you so much once again. I did come across the package but kind of got lost. You explain so well, its looking much more doable now. I will work with it and update here. Thank you very very much once again.
